# How can i change color of div by clicking on table column?

Tags: css, html, colors

Hi am trying to to do something like this

When i click first table column "one" then i need to change its  div color () to red from green.

when i click that again then it should change back to blue.  How can i do this??
 i have tried following code and its not working

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "blue");
}); 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>

    table{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    table td{
        width: 40px;
    }
    </style>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td >   
<div class="stileone" >
    Div Content
</div>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two Ways**

1. Load the script at the end of the body!

   ```
   <script>
   $(".stileone").on("click", function() {
     $(this).css("background", "blue");
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. Or, wrap in `$(document).ready(function(){})`

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".stileone").on("click", function() {
       $(this).css("background", "blue");
     });
   });
   </script>
   ```

**Reason**

When the script got executed, there was no DOM Object matching it. So, that's the reason the handler didn't attach to the element.

---

For your changing colours, you can do something like this.

```
$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).css("background") == "blue")
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    else if ($(this).css("background") == "red")
      $(this).css("background", "green");
    else if ($(this).css("background") == "green")
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
});
```

Comment: if i want to chnage the color of other divs in itehr column so apply the same code with differnt color ryt??

Comment: Yeah... Can you exactly say what you need to do?